# Should I use classified data for multi layer perceptron?

Tags: python, mlp

All columns' values are class labels. For example: value "1" for feature1 is <50. Namely, all features were classified. In this case, can I use the dataset for multi layer perceptron directly? Or Should I convert all columns to dummy variables?

```
Dataset:
    feature1 feature2 feature3 target
        5       1         4      1
        1       1         3      0
        9       3         2      1

Dummy:
     feature1_5  feature1_1  feature1_9 
          1         0           0      
          0         1           0        ...   
          0         0           1
```

Comment: What is the range of your features?

Comment: Feature1 : from 1 to 10    Feature2: from 1 to 3    Feature3: from 1 to 12

Comment: Have you looked into one-hot-encodings?

Comment: I have 8 features and some features have 10 classes. So one-hot-encoding will create many columns and also I have 3 million rows. So I wonder, label encoder is enough for mlp.